# new component inheriting existing html element angular

Tags: angular

I want to create custom button component with custom styling and functions. But I would like to inherit the properties, attributes of the button element like disabled.

So that I can directly use them from parent, instead of Input variable and assigning them for each one.

Is there anyway i can achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 7):

One way to augment a standard HTML element is to give the custom component an attribute selector. For example, the following component has the attribute selector `button[custom-button]`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button[custom-button]',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-button.component.css']
})
export class CustomButtonComponent {
  ...
}
```

You can then set the attribute `custom-button` on an HTML button, which becomes the host element of the component:

```
<button custom-button disabled (click)="onClick()">I am disabled</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnyzla?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.